# How to install and run Monodevelop 2.4.1 on Ubuntu 10.10 (Marevick)?

Tags: mono, monodevelop, ubuntu-10.10

I need .NET 4.0 but I was unable do find a PPA that allows me to install version 2.4.1 and the necessary dependencies.

Comment: MonoDevelop 2.4.1 will not give you a .NET 4 runtime. You need *Mono* 2.8 or later.

Comment: Probably I'll start developing on a vm with OpenSuse in order to have my development environment easily setup and give the focus more on the project than on the development environment.

Comment: I think that @mhutch is mistaken, according to MonoDevelop, 2.6 is when .NET 4.0 support started http://monodevelop.com/Download/What's_new_in_MonoDevelop_2.6

Comment: @mhutch Sorry, misread your answer and implication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

build the 2.8.2 from using the  the script here:

- http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/01/mono-2-8-2-script-updated-for-ubuntu-and-fedora/

and then installed the launchpad
 - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/i386/monodevelop/2.4+dfsg-3ubuntu2

and then in monodevelop:
Edit -> Preferences -> .Net Runtime and add the new source

Did that work?

Comment: I would strongly advise against replacing the system Mono. If building from source, build a parallel Mono environment. There are several guides to doing so: http://www.google.com/search?q=mono+parallel+environment

Comment: @mhutch - I just updated my answer.. is this an acceptable procedure?

Comment: I'me going to test this over this weekend.

Comment: @Chris: The install script looks fine, but it doesn't have anything about setting the environment. http://patrick.qmtech.net/blog/?p=36 looks better.

Comment: I'm the author of the mono script. I just added another experimental one that will install MonoDevelop 2.4.2 or 2.6 beta using the parallel environments method. It will also create a launcher script in the build folder that sets up the environment to run it. http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/03/monodevelop-2-4-and-2-6-beta-install-script-for-ubuntu-fedora/

Comment: @Nathan, I will have to check that out.  I have tested your mono build script on ubuntu and fedora and they worked great for me!

Comment: Currently, after several attempts, I consider at least for ASP.NET development that MonoDevelop doesn't fit all the needs for a web dev.

Right now using VS2010 on a Windows 7 VM and deploying directly to an arch server running mono via fastcgi on ligthttp is running fine with minor changes on we.config.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use this deb-package

http://blog.fusonic.net/2010/10/mono-2-8-parallel-environment-debianubuntu-package/

Comment: This is valid but currently I think the best way to work with the latest build is to use always on of the recommended platforms. In my case I want to use it on Linux for test purposes. The option was to work with a virtual machine tunning the latest Open Suse stable release. Focus :).

Answer (score 0):

Currently I think the best way to work with the latest build is to use always on of the recommended platforms. In my case I want to use it on Linux for test purposes. The option was to work with a virtual machine tuning the latest Open Suse stable release. Focus :).